# Extract cow number from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

every now and then my mom has to shift through these type of photos to extract the number from the image and rename it to the number.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm trying to use OpenCV, Python, Tesseract to get the process done. I'm really lost trying to extract the portion of the image with the numbers. How could I do this? Any suggestions i'm really new at OpenCV.

I tried to extract the white rectangular board using thresholds and contours, but no avail because the RGB I choose for thresh doesn't always work and I don't know how to choose the contour.

EDIT:

Looking at this paper http://yoni.wexlers.org/papers/2010TextDetection.pdf . Looks prominisn

Comment: Have you considered using [Mechanical Turk](https://requester.mturk.com/create/projects/new)?

Comment: Yes, but part of me wanted to take on the challenge :)

Answer (score 7):

I have been having another look at this, and had a couple of inspirations along the way....

1. Tesseract can accept custom dictionaries, and if you dig a little more, it appears that from v3.0, it accepts the command-line parameter `digits` to make it recognise digits only - seems a useful idea for your needs.
2. It may not be necessary to find the boards with the digits on - it may be easier to run Tesseract multiple times with various slices of the image and let it have a try itself as that is what it is supposed to do.

So, I decided to preprocess the image by changing everything that is within 25% of black to pure black, and everything else to pure white. That gives pre-processed images like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Next, I generate a series of images and pass them, one at a time to Tesseract. I decided to assume that the digits are probably between 40% to 10% of the image height, so I made a loop over strips 40, 30, 20 and 10% of the image height. I then slide the strip down the image from top to bottom in 20 steps passing each strip to Tesseract, till the strip is essentially across the bottom of the image.

Here are the 40% strips - each frame of the animation is passed to Tesseract:

[image]

Here are the 20% strips - each frame of the animation is passed to Tesseract:

[image]

Having got the strips, I resize them nicely for Tesseract's sweet spot and clean them up from noise etc. Then, I pass them into Tesseract and assess the quality of the recognition, somewhat crudely, by counting the number of digits it found. Finally, I sort the output by number of digits - presumably more digits is maybe better...

There are some rough edges and bits that you could dink around with, but it is a start!

```
#!/bin/bash
image=${1-c1.jpg}

# Make everything that is nearly black go fully black, everything else goes white. Median for noise
# convert -delay 500 c1.jpg c2.jpg c3.jpg -normalize -fuzz 25% -fill black -opaque black -fuzz 0 -fill white +opaque black -median 9 out.gif
   convert "${image}" -normalize \
       -fuzz 25% -fill black -opaque black \
       -fuzz 0   -fill white +opaque black \
       -median 9 tmp_$$.png 

# Get height of image - h
h=$(identify -format "%h" "${image}")

# Generate strips that are 40%, 30%, 20% and 10% of image height
for pc in 40 30 20 10; do
   # Calculate height of this strip in pixels - sh
   ((sh=(h*pc)/100))
   # Calculate offset from top of picture to top of bottom strip - omax
   ((omax=h-sh))
   # Calculate step size, there will be 20 steps
   ((step=omax/20))

   # Cut strips sh pixels high from the picture starting at top and working down in 20 steps
   for (( off=0;off<$omax;off+=$step)) do
      t=$(printf "%05d" $off)
      # Extract strip and resize to 80 pixels tall for tesseract
      convert tmp_$$.png -crop x${sh}+0+${off}      \
          -resize x80 -median 3 -median 3 -median 3 \
          -threshold 90% +repage slice_${pc}_${t}.png

      # Run slice through tesseract, seeking only digits
      tesseract slice_${pc}_${t}.png temp digits quiet

      # Now try and assess quality of output :-) ... by counting number of digits
      digits=$(tr -cd "[0-9]" < temp.txt)
      ndigits=${#digits}
      [ $ndigits -gt 0 ] && [ $ndigits -lt 6 ] && echo $ndigits:$digits
   done
done | sort -n
```

**Output for Cow 618** (first number is the number of digits found)

```
2:11
2:11
3:573
5:33613    <--- not bad
```

**Output for Cow 2755** (first number is the number of digits found)

```
2:51
3:071
3:191
3:517
4:2155   <--- pretty close
4:2755   <--- nailed that puppy :-)
4:2755   <--- nailed that puppy :-)
4:5212
5:12755  <--- pretty close
```

**Output for Cow 3174** (first number is the number of digits found)

```
3:554
3:734
5:12732
5:31741  <--- pretty close
```

Cool question - thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Using the PIL (Python Imaging Library) you can easily load images and process them. Using the [grayscale conversion](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imageops.htm#tag-ImageOps.grayscale), you can convert RGB to grayscale, which should be easier to detect levels. If you want to threshold the image (to detect the white boards), there is a [point() function](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.point) which lets you map the colors.

On the other hand, you could write a simple program, which lets you

- select, and show an image
- mark the area where the boards are
- crop the image
- apply tesseract or whatever,
- save the image with the detected number

That should facilitate the process a lot! Writing this should be relatively easy using TkInter, PyGTK, PyQt or some other windowing toolkit.

EDIT: I was needing a similar program to categorize images here - though not OCRing them. So I finally decided this was as good a time as any and made a first try (with OCR!). **Make a backup of your images before trying it out!**
Quick manual:

- Top left: Select the work folder, image list will appear if any images in the folder.
- Select image. Select area of image with number. Coordinates will appear in lower left corner, and program will call Tesseract.
- Edit - if necessary - the number OCRd in the dialog.
- Click Ok to accept - image will be renamed.

Here's the pre-alpha program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_pil.py
#  
#  Copyright 2015 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  

import pygtk
import gtk
import glob
import os.path as osp
from os import rename
import re
import subprocess as sp

temp_image = "/tmp/test_pil.png"
image_re = """\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$"""

class RecognizeDigits():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, img, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        """ Receive the gtk.Image, and the limits of the selected area (in
            window coordinates!)
            Call Tesseract on the area, and give the possibility to  edit the
            result.
            Returns None if NO is pressed, and the OCR'd (and edited) text if OK
        """
        pb = img.get_pixbuf().subpixbuf(x0, y0, x1-x0, y1-y0)
        pb.save(temp_image, "png")

        out = sp.check_output(("tesseract", temp_image, "stdout", "-psm 7", "digits"))
        out = out.replace(" ", "").strip()

        dlg = gtk.MessageDialog(type = gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION,
                                flags = gtk.DIALOG_MODAL,
                                buttons = gtk.BUTTONS_YES_NO,
                                message_format = "The number read is:")
        entry = gtk.Entry()
        entry.set_text(out)
        dlg.get_message_area().pack_start(entry)
        entry.show()
        response = dlg.run()
        nr = entry.get_text()

        dlg.destroy()

        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_YES:
            return nr
        else:
            return None

class FileSelector(gtk.VBox):
    """ Provides a folder selector (at the top) and a list of files in the
        selected folder. On selecting a file, the FileSelector calls the
        function provided to the constructor (image_viewer)
    """
    def __init__(self, image_viewer):
        gtk.VBox.__init__(self)
        self.image_viewer = image_viewer

        fc = gtk.FileChooserButton('Select a folder')
        fc.set_action(gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER)
        fc.connect("selection-changed", self.on_file_set)
        self.pack_start(fc, expand = False, fill = True)

        self.tstore = gtk.ListStore(str)
        self.tview = gtk.TreeView(self.tstore)
        self.tsel = self.tview.get_selection()
        self.tsel.connect("changed", self.on_selection_changed)
        renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = gtk.TreeViewColumn(None, renderer, text = 0)
        self.tview.append_column(col)

        scrw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrw.add(self.tview)
        self.pack_start(scrw, expand = True, fill = True)

    def on_file_set(self, fcb):
        self.tstore.clear()
        self.imgdir = fcb.get_filename()
        for f in glob.glob(self.imgdir + "/*"):
            if re.search(image_re, f):
                self.tstore.append([osp.basename(f)])

    def on_selection_changed(self, sel):
        model, itr = sel.get_selected()
        if itr != None:
            base = model.get(itr, 0)
            fname = self.imgdir + "/" + base[0]
            self.image_viewer(fname)

class Status(gtk.Table):
    """ Small status window which shows the coordinates for of the area
        selected in the image
    """
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Table.__init__(self)

        self.attach(gtk.Label("X"), 1, 2, 0, 1, yoptions = gtk.FILL)
        self.attach(gtk.Label("Y"), 2, 3, 0, 1, yoptions = gtk.FILL)
        self.attach(gtk.Label("Top left:"), 0, 1, 1, 2, yoptions = gtk.FILL)
        self.attach(gtk.Label("Bottom right:"), 0, 1, 2, 3, yoptions = gtk.FILL)

        self.entries = {}
        for coord in (("x0", 1, 2, 1, 2), ("y0", 2, 3, 1, 2),
                      ("x1", 1, 2, 2, 3), ("y1", 2, 3, 2, 3)):
            self.entries[coord[0]] = gtk.Entry()
            self.entries[coord[0]].set_width_chars(6)
            self.attach(self.entries[coord[0]],
                                     coord[1], coord[2], coord[3], coord[4],
                                     yoptions = gtk.FILL)

    def set_top_left(self, x0, y0):
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0
        self.entries["x0"].set_text(str(x0))
        self.entries["y0"].set_text(str(y0))

    def set_bottom_right(self, x1, y1):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.entries["x1"].set_text(str(x1))
        self.entries["y1"].set_text(str(y1))

class ImageViewer(gtk.ScrolledWindow):
    """ Provides a scrollwindow to move the image around. It also detects
        button press and release events (left button), will call status
        to update the coordinates, and will call task on button release
    """
    def __init__(self, status, task = None):
        gtk.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self)

        self.task = task
        self.status = status
        self.drawing = False
        self.prev_rect = None

        self.viewport = gtk.Viewport()
        self.viewport.connect("button-press-event", self.on_button_pressed)
        self.viewport.connect("button-release-event", self.on_button_released)
        self.viewport.set_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | \
                                 gtk.gdk.BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK)

        self.img = gtk.Image()
        self.viewport.add(self.img)
        self.add(self.viewport)

    def set_image(self, fname):
        self.imagename = fname
        self.img.set_from_file(fname)

    def on_button_pressed(self, viewport, event):
        if event.button == 1:       # Left button: Select rectangle start
            #self.x0, self.y0 = self.translate_coordinates(self.img, int(event.x), int(event.y))
            self.x0, self.y0 = int(event.x), int(event.y)
            self.status.set_top_left(self.x0, self.y0)
            self.drawing = True

    def on_button_released(self, viewport, event):
        if event.button == 1:       # Right button: Select rectangle end
            #self.x1, self.y1 = self.translate_coordinates(self.img, int(event.x), int(event.y))
            self.x1, self.y1 = int(event.x), int(event.y)
            self.status.set_bottom_right(self.x1, self.y1)
            if self.task != None:
                res = self.task().process(self.img, self.x0, self.y0, self.x1, self.y1)

                if res == None: return

                newname = osp.split(self.imagename)[0] + '/' + res + ".jpeg"
                rename(self.imagename, newname)
                print "Renaming ", self.imagename, newname

class MainWindow(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("delete-event", self.on_delete_event)
        self.set_size_request(600, 300)

        grid = gtk.Table()

        # Image selector
        files = FileSelector(self.update_image)
        grid.attach(files, 0, 1, 0, 1,
                           yoptions = gtk.FILL | gtk.EXPAND, xoptions = gtk.FILL)

        # Some status information
        self.status = Status()
        grid.attach(self.status, 0, 1, 1, 2,
                                 yoptions = gtk.FILL, xoptions = gtk.FILL)

        # The image viewer
        self.viewer = ImageViewer(self.status, RecognizeDigits)
        grid.attach(self.viewer, 1, 2, 0, 2)
        self.add(grid)

        self.show_all()

    def update_image(self, fname):
        self.viewer.set_image(fname)

    def on_delete_event(self, wdg, data):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def run(self):
        gtk.mainloop()

def main():
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.run()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you jcoppens! Will do it like this. Finding the numbers by algo is out of reach for me

Comment: An even more basic step - maybe before the image recognition by tesseract - could be showing the image, and typing the number. The program can then do the renaming of the image. You can then insert the call to tesseract later.

Comment: This is a good idea... if you can't fully automate the process, you could at least produce a tool to take the manual process and make it **much** faster for the person doing the processing.

Comment: THANK YOU! For whoever uses this in the future, tesseract stout param not working in windows. Thanks again jcoppens

Comment: There are probably some other problems and annoyances in the program. Eg. I couldn't find a simple way to draw the selection rectangle. I couldn't find any reference to `stdout` (not stout ;) that's something else) not working on Windows though. Sure it's not `check_output()` which fails? Can you type the command on the command line?

Answer (score 4):

I come up a pretty simple solution with the help of opencv.

1. Resize the image in order to prune outlier by contours(easier to measure the area)

   ```
   std::string const img_name = "cow_00";
   Mat input = imread("../forum_quest/data/" + img_name + ".jpg");
   cout<<input.size()<<endl;
   if(input.empty()){
       cerr<<"cannot open image\n";
       return;
   }
   if(input.cols > 1000){
       cv::resize(input, input, {1000, (int)(1000.0/input.cols * input.rows)}, 0.25, 0.25);
   }
   ```
2. Crop the region on top of 1/3

   ```
   //Assume the text always lie on top 1/3 of the image
   Mat crop_region;
   input(Rect(0, 0, input.cols, input.rows/3)).copyTo(crop_region);
   ```
3. Extract foreground

   ```
   cv::Mat fore_ground_extract(cv::Mat const &input)
   {
       vector<Mat> bgr;
       split(input, bgr);

       //process on blue channel as andrew suggest, because it is
       //easier to get rid of vegetation
       Mat text_region = bgr[0];
       medianBlur(text_region, text_region, 5);
       threshold(text_region, text_region, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU);

       //further remove small noise, unwanted border
       Mat const erode_kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, {11, 11});
       erode(text_region, text_region, erode_kernel);
       Mat const dilate_kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, {7, 7});
       dilate(text_region, text_region, dilate_kernel);

       //change the text from black to white, easier to extract as contours
       bitwise_not(text_region, text_region);

       return text_region;
   }
   ```

[image]

[image]

[image]

4. Extract contour, you can use ERFilter to extract the text if accuracy of contours are low

   ```
   std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> get_text_contours(cv::Mat const &input)
   {
       //Find the contours of candidate text, remove outlier with
       //some contour properties
       //Try ERFilter of opencv if accuracy of this solution is low
       vector<cpoints> contours;
       findContours(input, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
       auto outlier = [](cpoints const &cp)
       {
           auto const rect = cv::boundingRect(cp);

           return rect.width > rect.height && (rect.area() < 900 || rect.area() >= 10000);
       };
       auto it = std::remove_if(std::begin(contours), std::end(contours), outlier);
       contours.erase(it, std::end(contours));

       std::sort(std::begin(contours), std::end(contours), [](cpoints const &lhs, cpoints const &rhs)
       {
           return cv::boundingRect(lhs).x < cv::boundingRect(rhs).x;
       });

       return contours;
   }
   ```
5. Create character classifier and loop through the text candidate

   ```
       string const vocabulary = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; // must have the same order as the classifier output classes
       Ptr<text::OCRHMMDecoder::ClassifierCallback> ocr = text::loadOCRHMMClassifierCNN("OCRBeamSearch_CNN_model_data.xml.gz");
       vector<int> out_classes;
       vector<double> out_confidences;
       for(size_t i = 0; i < text_contours.size(); ++i){
           Scalar const color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
           drawContours(text_mask, text_contours, static_cast<int>(i), color, 2);
           auto const text_loc = boundingRect(text_contours[i]);
           //crop_region can gain highest accuracy since it is trained on scene image
           rectangle(crop_region, text_loc, color, 2);
           ocr->eval(crop_region(text_loc), out_classes, out_confidences);
           cout << "OCR output = \"" << vocabulary[out_classes[0]]
                   << "\" with confidence "
                   << out_confidences[0] << std::endl;
           putText(crop_region, string(1, vocabulary[out_classes[0]]),  Point(text_loc.x, text_loc.y - 5),
               FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);

           imshow("text_mask", text_mask);
           imshow("crop_region", crop_region(text_loc));
           waitKey();
       }
   ```

Results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Complete source codes is place at [github](https://github.com/stereomatchingkiss/blogCodes2/blob/master/forum_quest/extract_cow_number.cpp)

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking at this a little and thinking how I might tackle it. I prefer the free ImageMagick software which is available for OSX, installed on most Linux distros and available for Windows.

My first reaction was to try a Sobel edge detector to the images, then threshold that and remove noise and outliers with a median filter.

I can do all that with a single command at the commandline like this:

```
convert c1.jpg                                                          \
   -define convolve:scale='50%!' -bias 50% -morphology Convolve Sobel   \
   -solarize 50% -level 50,0% -auto-level -threshold 50% -median 3 result.jpg
```

where `c1.jpg` is your first cow, and likewise for the other cows.

I end up with this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

which is a pretty reasonable starting point for working out where the numbers are in the image. I am thinking of dividing the image into tiles next, or other techniques, and then I will look at tiles/areas containing the most white. That way I will start to get a handle on where I should be pointing `tesseract` to look... however, it is bedtime - apparently. Maybe someone clever like @rayryeng will take a look overnight :-)

Comment: Some suggestions if go this path: there are forms which detect in both directions. see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#edge. However, generally pattern recognition for characters works better if the 'fill' is not lost. It gives the algorithm more information to work with. Doing a correlation between stored digits and the scanned ones would do nicely. An interesting path would be edge detection to detect the boards comparing to rectangles, then OCR on the original image, cropped.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked this problem but I am unfamiliar with OpenCV and Python, so I present a partial solution in Matlab. The idea is the important part, and the code is just for reference. I think using my image processing  possibly augmented with mark's windowing idea could give you favorable results.

These images have a ton of vegetation in them and vegetation is typically high in greens and reds. I process only the blue channel which removes a lot of the vegetation and still leaves the white signs easily identifiable. I then use `otsus` method for thresholding something like this in OpenCV `cv::threshold(im_gray, img_bw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);` but then I take 1.5 times the given threshold. so the threshold is still image specific by `otsu`, but also very selective. At this point you have a pretty good image.

Then we just clean the image with some erosion and dilation. Also note that that my dilation element is slightly larger than my erosion one. You then have images with fairly clean numbers. Maybe tesserect could even just process the image at this point, or you can try it with the windowing.

I know OpenCV has these same functions, but as I said I just did what I was familiar with. I hope it helps you. here are my results:

[image: processed images]

and the code

```erlang
%382 is 255*1.5 so basically we are taking the auto threshold and raising it by
%50 percent. graythresh is performing otsu thresholding
bim = im(:,:,3) > graythresh(im(:,:,3))*382;
bim1 = im1(:,:,3) > graythresh(im1(:,:,3))*382;
bim2 = im2(:,:,3) > graythresh(im2(:,:,3))*382;

%se and se2 are what opencv would call getStructuringElement using a 
%MORPH_ELLIPSE
se = strel('disk',3);
eim = imerode(bim,se);
eim1 = imerode(bim1,se);
eim2 = imerode(bim2,se);

%se and se2 are what opencv would call getStructuringElement using a 
%MORPH_ELLIPSE
se2 = strel('disk',5);
dim = imdilate(eim,se2);
dim1 = imdilate(eim1,se2);
dim2 = imdilate(eim2,se2);

subplot(3,3,1);imshow(bim);title('blue thresholded');
subplot(3,3,2);imshow(bim1);title('');
subplot(3,3,3);imshow(bim2);title('');

subplot(3,3,4);imshow(eim);title('after errosion');
subplot(3,3,5);imshow(eim1);title('');
subplot(3,3,6);imshow(eim2);title('');

subplot(3,3,7);imshow(dim);title('after dilation');
subplot(3,3,8);imshow(dim1);title('');
subplot(3,3,9);imshow(dim2);title('');
```