# Get a map of where text was detected using tesseract in Python

Tags: python, tesseract

I am trying to write a code which, given an image, will run tessearct on the entire image and return a map of all locations where text was detected (as a binary image).

It doesn't have to be pixel-by-pixel, a union of bounding boxes is more than enough.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Yes... (of course). Look at the Python imaging library for loading the image, and cropping it. Then you can apply Tesseract on each piece and check the output.

Have a look [at the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923827/extract-cow-number-from-image) I answered a while back. It might help you with the elements you need. It lets you manually select and area, and OCR it. But that can be easily changed.

Comment: This sounds like you're solving a very different problem.

Comment: Note entirely. The poster wanted to draw a window, and do OCR in that window. But if you throw away that part of the program (making the selection), then you could calculate the subdivisions in a small loop, and do the OCR in each. In the original program the goal was to rename the file with the number recognized. You can throw that part away too. The program will get a lot shorter!

Comment: `union of bounding boxes` you mean subdividing the image in N x M boxes, for example? Then applying OCR?

Comment: I read exactly the opposite: the OP wants to detect text, and use the location of found text to draw a window.

Comment: With window, I do not mean draw something on the image, but extract a 'rectangle' of data, analyze it for text. Anyway, it seems the poster is not here to correct us?

Comment: Sorry, it was a holiday. I need to figure out where there is text. Breaking the image into a grid and then doing OCR in each square is unfortunately too coarse for the problem I am trying to solve.