# Using tesseract in Python3 textract library

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I would like to extract text from PDF files. I could successfully install tesseract (it works in Terminal) and textract (following [this](http://www.tysonmaly.com/installing-textract-for-python-3/) instruction).

However, when I run the code, I got an error.

```
text = textract.process(
    '/Users/Text/en.pdf',
    method='tesseract',
    language='eng',
)
```

Error is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/textract-1.4.0-py3.4.egg/textract/parsers/pdf_parser.py in extract_tesseract(self, filename, **kwargs)
     62                 page_content = TesseractParser().extract(page_path, **kwargs)
     63                 contents.append(page_content)
---> 64             return ''.join(contents)
     65         finally:
     66             shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

I tried several modifications, but they never work and I got the same error.

1. `return b''.join(contents)`
2. Insert `contents = [str(item) for item in contents]` before `return`
3. Insert `contents = [item.decode("utf-8") for item in contents]` before `return`

Comment: You were absolutely right - my apologies. I somehow missed that line in your modifications. I tested your example here - tesseract 3.03 and leptonica 1.70, on a Slackware Linux system, and it seems to run without problem from the command line. Did you try that? `tesseract test_text.png  out`

Comment: BTW, I removed my reply to avoid confusion...

Comment: @jcoppens Thanks for checking. Actually, I also tried in Command Line. But since I need to edit the text in Python after extraction, the most convenient way is doing everything in Python.

Comment: I believe I tried once to use the tesseract wrapper, but couldn't get it to work properly. In this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923827/extract-cow-number-from-image/29927200#29927200, I've called tesseract 'manually' from the program, and its output is then processed inside Python. Don't panic - the code is long because it also includes GUI code. The call is in the first class (RecognizeDigits) - the two lines of code starting with `out`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I did the same question in [Japanese Stackoverflow (スタックオーバーフロー)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27591/python3%E3%81%A7tesseract%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%9Focr%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC/27672#27672) and got the solution. The following is my translation of the core part. (thanks, @mjy).

Note: This modification works at least for English.

1. In line 64 of `pdf_parser.py`
   Change `return ''.join(contents)` to

   ```
   return "".join(item.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(item, bytes) else item for item in contents)
   ```
2. However, another error occurs.

   `NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined`
3. In line 54 of `utils.py`, change `if isinstance(text, unicode): (...cont...)` to

   ```
   if isinstance(text, str):
       return text
   ```